# Vectors with Arrow Under Symbol

Tags: vector

My professor uses arrows below the symbol to denote vectors (example below), and I couldn't figure out how to do this in LaTeX. I tried

```
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\underset{\rightarrow}{#1}}
```

but it takes up too much space below the symbol. Is there a way to typeset this, similar to the undertilde package?

Thanks![image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with the `accents` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{accents}
\newcommand\undervec[1]{\underaccent{\vec}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\[ {\undervec{ω}}_{21}= \undervec{\mathcal F}_2^{T}{ω_{21}} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this without any extra packages just by fiddling with boxes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\mathchardef\arr="017E % character 7E from textfont 1 is the vector arrow 
\renewcommand\vec[1]{\setbox0=\hbox{$#1$}\lower2ex\hbox to 0pt{\hbox to \wd0{\hss$\arr\;$\hss}\hss}\box0}
\begin{document}
\[\vec\omega_{21} = \vec{\mathcal F}_2^T \omega_{21}= \vec i\]
\end{document}
```

to produce

[image]

although I expect the `accents` package is more robust.

Comment: please don't give bad examples using $$ … $$ :o; in LaTeX documents.

Comment: was it just the $$ or is the rest bad too?

Comment: It was just that, the rest is fine.